# Getting error while mounting nfs with error mount.nfs: Remote I/O error

Tags: linux, nfs

When you are mounting AIX nfs shares, the following error may be obtained:

```
mount.nfs: Remote I/O error

Aix NFS server with NFSv4 protocol support
This may be due to a misconfiguration of NFSv4 on the Aix NFS server

Aix NFS server without NFSv4 protocol support
To resolve the issue, mount the nfs share with an option vers=3. Eg:

Raw
# mount -o vers=3 server_ip_addr:dir local_mount_point
```

Comment: seems off-topic for SO, more suited to Super User, but they might want more context too such as _which_ shares you tried to mount and _how_.

Comment: As said it was nfs share